# Why does an instance of Access quit when opened from VBA after the macro is finished running?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am wondering if someone has encountered this before. When I create an instance of Access (2013) through VBA, the Access application quits when the macro is finished running even though I don't have any `Application.quit` statement anywhere in the subroutine. Any ideas?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim axApp As Access.Application
    Set axApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    axApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Access application instance is created and referenced by the *axApp* object variable.

At the end of your procedure *axApp* goes out of scope and is destroyed.  As a result of its destruction, the Access application instance it references is closed.

If you want that Access instance to stick around after your VBA procedure is done, set its `.UserControl` property to True.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim axApp As Access.Application
    Set axApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    axApp.Visible = True
    axApp.UserControl = True
End Sub
```